# How can I enable Emacs key bindings in Microsoft Visual C# 2008 Express Edition?

Tags: visual-studio, emacs

How can I enable Emacs key bindings in Microsoft Visual C# 2008 Express Edition?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the Emacs keybinding file (**Emacs.vsk**) it's not included on Visual Studio Express Editions, however you might be able to find it and use it :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [XKeymacs](http://www.cam.hi-ho.ne.jp/oishi/indexen.html), which can enable Emacs-like keybindings in *all* Windows applications.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, install Visual C++ Express Edition. It includes the emacs keybindings.